# binary montgomery multiplication

Tags: cryptography

In the paper [paper-montgomery-multiplication](https://waset.org/publications/9996895/modified-montgomery-for-rsa-cryptosystem) there are a lot of algorithm explained how to make a montgomery multiplication on bit level.
But I have problems to understand that correctly.

I have written Algorithm 1 (page 2 in paper) in Verilog (just testbench).

```
module mmul();
    parameter k = 6;


    reg [7:0] a;
    reg [7:0] b;
    reg [7:0] s;
    reg [7:0] q;
    reg [7:0] n;

    integer i;


    initial 
    begin
        a = 13;
        b = 17;
        n = 41;

        s = 0;
        for(i=0; i<k; i = i + 1)
        begin
            q[i] = (s+a[i]*b)%2;
            s = (s+a[i]+b+q[i]*n)/2;
        end

        if(s>=n)
            s = s-n;

        $display("%d",s);       

        $finish();
    end
endmodule
```

I expect that 13*17  % 41  results 16
because 13*17 % 41 = 221 % 17
   -> 221 - floor(221/41)*41 = 16

This program results with 23. I know that this algorithm S= A×B*2^(-k) mod n. What I have to do, so that the program delivers the right result?